# How do I filter out invisible characters without affecting Japanese character set?

Tags: ruby, character, cjk

I noticed that some of my input is getting `U+2028`. I don't know what this is, but how can I prevent this with consideration of UTF-8 and English/Japanese characters?

Answer (score 3):

The character `U+2028` is [LINE SEPARATOR](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) and is one of space characters.

To select only the Japanese characters is (I am afraid) quite tricky in the Unicode space, because CJK characters spread all over across so many planes, even though Ruby supports an extensive Unicode *category* format in `Regexp` like `\p{Hiragana}`.  However, if your only interest is Japanese and ASCII, the NKF library is useful.  Here is an example:

```
require 'nkf'
orig = "b2αÇ()あ相〜\u2028\u3000＿━●★】"
p orig
p NKF.nkf('-w -E', NKF.nkf('-e', orig))

# =>
# "b2αÇ()あ相〜\u2028　＿━●★】"
# "b2α()あ相〜　＿━●★】"
```

As you see, the unicode character `U+2028` is filtered out, whereas a Greek character "α" is preserved because it is included in the Japanese JIS-X-0208 code. Note the accented alphabets like "Ç" are filtered out, because they are not included.  The set of so-called hankaku-kana is <strike>filtered out</strike> (*Edited-from*) converted into zenkaku-kana (*Edited-to*) in this formula. The JIS-X-0212 character set is not supported, either.

A solution for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with other solutions (for Ruby 2) in addition to the solution with the NKF library. The comparison as described below is in a way *interesting*, as they are slightly different from one another.  This is a major revision, and so I am posting it as a separate answer. I am also describing the background about this at the end of this post.
I am assuming the original input is in UTF-8 encoding except for the first section (if not, convert it to the UTF-8 first to apply any of the examples).

### Solutions to filtering out illegitimate characters

"*illegitimate*" means the character code that is not included in the encoding defined for a String instance.
In Ruby 2, such String usually should have the encoding `ASCII-8BIT`.  However, some may wrongly have `UTF-8` encoding.

If it has the encoding `ASCII-8BIT`, but if you want to get a legitimate `UTF-8` String,

```
s1 = String.new("あ\x99", encoding: 'ASCII-8BIT')  # An example ASCII-8BIT
                    # => "\xE3\x81\x82\x99"
s1.encoding         # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
s1.valid_encoding?  # => true because 'ASCII-8BIT' accepts anything.

s1.force_encoding('UTF-8')
                    # => s1=="あ\x99"
s1.valid_encoding?  # => false

s2 = s1.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, replace: '')
                    # => "あ"
s2.valid_encoding?  # => true
```

If it has wrongly the encoding `UTF-8`, and if you want to filter out the illegitimate codepoints,

```
s1 = String.new("あ\x99", encoding: 'UTF-8')  # An example 'UTF-8'
                    # => "あ\x99"
s1.encoding         # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
s1.valid_encoding?  # => false
s2 = s1.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, replace: '')
                    # => "あ"
s2.valid_encoding?  # => true
```

### Solutions to filtering out "non-Japanese" characters

All the following methods are to filter out "**non-Japanese**" characters.
Basically, "**non-Japanese**" characters are those that are not included in one or more of the traditional standard of the Japanese character set.
See the next section for the detailed background of the definition of the "**non-Japanese**" characters.

The strategy here is to convert the encoding of the original String to a Japanese JIS encoding (referred to as `ISO-2022-JP` or `EUC-JP`; basically JIS-X-0208) and to convert back to `UTF-8`.

#### Use `String#encode`

Ruby-2 built-in `String#encode` does the exact job.

```
orig = "b2◇〒α()あ相〜\u3000＿８Ｄ━●★】$£€Ç♡㌔③\u2028ﾊﾝｶｸ"
print "Orig:"; p orig
print "Enc: "; p orig.encode('ISO-2022-JP', undef: :replace, replace: '').encode('UTF-8')
```

**Characteristics**

- "zenkaku-alnum": preserved
- "hankaku-kana": filtered out
- Euro-sign: filtered out
- Latin1: filtered out
- JISX0212: filtered out
- CJK Compatibility: filtered out
- Circled Digit: filtered out
- Unicode [Line Separator](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/): filtered out

#### Use NKF library

The NKF library is one of the standard libraries that come with the official Ruby release.
The library is traditional and has been used for decades; cf., NKF stands for [Network Kanji Filter](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Kanji_Filter).
It does a very similar, though slightly different, job to/from Ruby Encoding.

```
orig = "b2◇〒α()あ相〜\u3000＿８Ｄ━●★】$£€Ç♡㌔③\u2028ﾊﾝｶｸ"
require 'nkf'
print "NKF: "; p NKF.nkf('-w -E', NKF.nkf('-e', orig))
```

**Characteristics**

- "zenkaku-alnum": preserved
- "hankaku-kana": converted into "zenkaku" (aka full-width)
- Euro-sign: filtered out
- Latin1: filtered out
- JISX0212: filtered out
- CJK Compatibility: preserved
- Circled Digit: preserved
- Unicode [Line Separator](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/): filtered out

#### Use iconv Gem

Ruby Gem [`iconv`](https://rubygems.org/gems/iconv/) does not come with the standard Ruby anymore (I think it used to, up to Ruby 2.1 or something).  But you can easily install it with the gem command like `gem install iconv` .

It can handle `ISO-2022-JP-2`, unlike the above-mentioned 2 methods, which may be handy (n.b., the encoding ISO-2022-JP-2 is actually defined in Ruby Encoding, but no conversion is defiend for or from it in Ruby in default).  Once installed, the following is an example.

```
orig = "b2◇〒α()あ相〜\u3000＿８Ｄ━●★】$£€Ç♡㌔③\u2028ﾊﾝｶｸ"
require 'iconv'
output = ''
Iconv.open('iso-2022-jp-2', 'utf-8') do |cd|
  cd.discard_ilseq=true
  output = cd.iconv orig << cd.iconv(nil)
end
s2 = Iconv.conv('utf-8', 'iso-2022-jp-2', output)
print "Icon:"; p s2
```

**Characteristics**

- "zenkaku-alnum": preserved
- "hankaku-kana": preserved
- Euro-sign: preserved
- Latin1: preserved
- JISX0212: preserved
- CJK Compatibility: filtered out
- Circled Digit: preserved
- Unicode [Line Separator](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/): filtered out

#### Summary

Here are the outputs of the above-mentioned three methods:

```
Orig:"b2◇〒α()あ相〜　＿８Ｄ━●★】$£€Ç♡㌔③\u2028ﾊﾝｶｸ"
Enc: "b2◇〒α()あ相〜　＿８Ｄ━●★】$£"
NKF: "b2◇〒α()あ相〜　＿８Ｄ━●★】$£㌔③ハンカク"
Icon:"b2◇〒α()あ相〜　＿８Ｄ━●★】$£€Ç♡③ﾊﾝｶｸ"
```

All the code snippets above here are available as a [gist in Github](https://gist.github.com/masasakano/10703ccb621d08c51f7e19e8900ea0ae) for convenience — download or `git clone` and run it.

---

### Background

What is an invalid character?  The character `U+2028`, for example as in the question, is a legitimate UTF-8 character ([Line Separator](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/)).  So, there is no *general* reason to filter such characters out, though some individual situations may require to.

What is an English character?  The lower- and upper-case alphabets (52 in total) probably are. Then, how about the dollar sign ($)? Pound sign (£)? Euro sign (€)?  The dollar sign is an ASCII character, whereas neither of the pound and Euro signs is not. The pound sign is included in the traditional Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) character set, whereas the Euro sign is not.  As such, what is an English character is not a trivial question.
You may define ASCII (or Latin-1, or whatever) is the only English character set in your definition, but it is somewhat arbitrary.

What is a Japanese character?  OK, Hiragana and Katakana are unique to Japanese. How about Kanji? Do you accept simplified Chinese characters, which are not used in Japan, as Kanji? How about symbols? OK, a few symbols, such as `。` (`U+3002`; [Ideographic Full Stop](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3002/)) and `「` (`U+300c`; [Left Corner Bracket](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/300c/])) are essential punctuations in the Japanese text. But, is there any reason to regard characters like `▼` ([Black Down-Pointing Triangle](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/)), which has been used widely among Japanese-language computer users for decades, as Japanese specific? Perhaps not. They are just symbols that can be used anywhere in the world. And worse, it is not a clear cut; for example, although it is perhaps fair to argue [Postal Mark](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3012/) `〒` is Japanese specific, it is not an essential punctuation like the full stop but just a symbol fairly popularly used in Japan. I would not be surprised if the very similar symbol is actually used elsewhere in the world, unknown to me.

Being similar to the argument of ASCII and Latin-1 for English characters, you could define the traditionally used characters included in the JIS (X 0208) character set are the valid Japanese characters. Again, it is inevitably arbitrary. For example, the Pound sign (£) is included in it, whereas Euro sign is not. The diamond mark `◇` ([White Diamond](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25c7/)) is included, whereas the heart mark `♡` ([White Heart Suit](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2661/)) is not. Or, what about those so-called "zenkaku" (aka full-width) characters, which are just duplications of alphabets and Arabic numerals of 0 to 9 of ASCII?

After all, the Unicode is the **unified** set of the characters used in the world regardless of the languages (— well, ideally at least, though you may argue the real Unicode is not quite idealistic).  In this sense there is **no definite answer** to filter out non-English or non-Japanese characters. Consequently, the original question about filtering out `U+2028` is one of those arbitrary demands coming from some specific situations, even though it can well be a popular demand in fact (and hence my answer).

Only the definitive thing you could do is to filter out illegitimate characters for the chosen character encoding, such as UTF-8, as described in the first section of this answer. The rest is, really, up to each individual's need in their specific situations.

#### Background of the "Japanese" character sets

The Japanese character set was traditionally defined in the JIS standards in the official term. Specifically, [JIS-X-0208](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0208) and much less popular [JIS-X-0212](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0212) (often casually called "補助漢字") are the two standards (n.b., they have their specific details like 1983 and 1990). Unfortunately, in practice, NEC, Microsoft and Apple adopted their own variations (called broadly `Shift_JIS` or `SJIS`, though each has their own variation). Due to the popularity of their OSs, they were (and to some extent still are(!)) more widely used in Japan in reality than the strict official ones before the era where the UTF-8 is widely accepted.

Note that all of them accept the ASCII at least.  So, it has been always safe to use ASCII in pretty much any situations (excepting some in early 80s or before).

The Unicode is very inclusive, containing pretty much any of the characters that have been defined in any of these character codesets. That means any of the characters that have once stirred hot debate (whether you should not use or you may) can be legitimately used in (any of) the Unicode encoding now – I mean *legitimate* as far as the character encoding is concerned.

I presume this confused practical situation has lead to the results as shown above that slightly differ from one another, depending which method you use.  Pick your favourite, depending on your need!